# Register 2 peripheral UUID with 1 service, NRF52

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, nrf52832

I have 3 nrf52 boards: 2 act as peripheral and 1 as central device.

I want to register 2 different UUID's for the 2 peripheral devices, which contain the same service (0x0001 - NUS for example).
I add UUID's using `sd_ble_uuid_vs_add(..)` function and set `common_enable_params.vs_uuid_count = 2`. After that I register service with `ble_db_discovery_evt_register(..)` function.

The problem is - I get data from only from 1 peripheral (from UUID, that was registered using `sd_ble_uuid_vs_add(..)` first).

How can I register more than 1 peripheral UUID with the same service?

Comment: I recommend posting this question on the Nordic DevZone so Nordic Engineers can help you out. They're very quick and helpful and you will probably get a response within a week. Your second bet would be StackOverflow as programming questions are posted there.